# Servlet mapping issue with websphere

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, web.xml

Following is my servlet mapping:

Path: EAR/WAR/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetChartDetails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.high.GetChartDetails</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetChartDetails</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Following in the location of my JSP:

Path: war/Monitor/XYZ.jsp

Inside this jsp, I am trying to make ajax call by calling above servlet as follows:

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
        url:"http://localhost:25014/Monitor/GetChartDetails?        jsonp="+chartType,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: chartType,
        error: function () {
        alert("Error is occured");
        }
        });

chartType is a string. I am getting the alert as "Error is occured" and servlet is not being called.

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: I am assuming the context root of your web application is `Monitor`? You are mapping your servlet to `/` so try `http://localhost:25014/Monitor/?jsonp="+chartType` instead

Comment: Issue got resolved. I changed the servlet mapping. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved by changing the servlet mapping.